# How can I ask a professor for time-sensitive information when they are out for a family emergency?

Tags: interpersonal-issues

I'm an undergraduate student, and at the start of the semester I was trying to organize something like undergraduate research (but more basic) with one of my professors. I have to fill out a form due at the end of the third week of the semester describing what the work would be, so I went to this professor during the first week of classes to discuss potential options.

About a week later, near the end of the second week of classes, I sent an email with additional research I had done on potential topics that looked promising based on what I found on their CV. They responded and told me that they would get back to me later with what they felt would work best.

The form is due at the end of this week, but the professor just sent an email out to the class that their office hours were cancelled and they would not be in class due to a family emergency. I obviously don't want them to feel any pressure, but at the same time, this is a time sensitive process for me.

What's the best way to ask for basic information about the project so I can begin working on the form?

Comment: Sometimes these things will have a faculty member who is in charge of the program overall even if they are not your advisor specifically (e.g. head of undergrad research in the department or something like that). Is there any identifiable point person you can explain your situation to / request an extension?

Comment: @TPM that's a good point, I'll make sure to do that.

Comment: @TPM, it would be best to make that an answer.

Comment: @TPM Yes I think that's the correct approach.

Comment: Keep in mind that the administration (or whoever is collecting the form) were probably expecting that you would have discussed the project with the professor well before the semester started.  So the fact that you only started these discussions in the first week of classes may seem to them like you left it until the last minute, and they may not be inclined to be lenient with the deadlines or requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I'm an academic who has had to cancel class and office hours due to emergencies myself. We are all pretty tied to email these days wherever we happen to be, and regardless of what is going on in our personal lives, our professional responsibilities to continue to limp along. Depending on the specific nature of the emergency and the demands on their time, the professor may actually be able to help you nevertheless, but i) may well need reminding, and ii) may have higher priorities at this time.

I would send an email like the following (and if I received it, would respond as positively as I am able if the tone does not rub me the wrong way.)

> Dear Professor X:
>
> I understand you have had a family emergency. Sorry to bother you at
>   such a time, and I fully understand if you are therefore unable to
>   respond to this email. However, in case you happen to be working
>   remotely, I would much appreciate your comments on the below, since I
>   need to ... by .....  Or is there someone else you would recommend I
>   contact instead given the timeline?
>
> Thanks and apologies, ...